# pass php array variable in google bar charts

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables, google-visualization

I have a bar graph code in javascript which consist of fields such as topic1, topic2  and so on as shown below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


    // Draw the chart and set the chart values
    function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

     ['Task', 'Weak Area'],
     ['Topic 1', 3],
     ['Topic 2', 5],
     ['Topic 3', 4],
     ['Topic 4', 1],
     ['Topic 5', 8]
     ]);

     var chart = new 
     google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('Topic'));
     chart.draw(data, options);
     }
    </script>
```

and i have a php array variable in the same page with value as:

```
   foreach($_SESSION['elements'] as $value) {
    print $value;
    $type[]= $value;
   }
```

which has value as:

```
   Array ( [19] => create [20] => code )
```

now i want the code to be some thing so as to replace the topic1, topic2 and so on with the elements of array, such as :

```
      ['Task', 'Weak Area'],
     ['create', 3],
     ['code', 5],
     ]);
```

as above there are only two elements in array...
can someone please suggest or help me out.

Answer (score 0):

If 'task' and 'weak area' are constant you can try something like:

```
 foreach($_SESSION['elements'] as $value) {
    $type[]= $value;
 }
 $type[] = 'task';
 $type[] = 'weak area';

 $chartData = json_encode($type);
```

Then in your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chartData = [<?=$charData;?>];

function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);
```

Comment: it says table has no columns